# systemd-nspawn OS container is unusable because I can't set the root password

Tags: fedora, selinux, container, systemd-nspawn

I combined the detailed instructions from the original [blog post](http://0pointer.net/blog/systemd-for-administrators-part-xxi.html), and the more up to date instructions from the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) (using dnf instead of yum).

```
# sudo dnf -y --releasever=24 --installroot=$HOME/fedora-24 --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=fedora --enablerepo=updates install systemd passwd dnf fedora-release vim-minimal

# sudo systemd-nspawn -D fedora-24
Spawning container fedora-24 on /home/alan-sysop/fedora-24
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
-bash-4.3# passwd
Changing password for user root.
New password:
Retype new password:
```

Result:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

and an AVC popup, i.e. SELinux error.  It says `passwd` is not allowed to unlink (replace) `/etc/passwd`.  One of the suggestions from the "Troubleshoot" button is that I could assign the label `passwd_file_t` to `/etc/passwd`.

What's wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, dnf didn't set the "right" SELinux label on /etc/passwd.  But it did set a label on /bin/passwd.  That mismatch is what causes the problem.  Further explanations welcomed :).

```
$ ls -Z fedora-24/etc/passwd
unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 fedora-24/etc/passwd
$ ls -Z /etc/passwd
system_u:object_r:passwd_file_t:s0 /etc/passwd

$ ls -Z fedora-24/bin/passwd
system_u:object_r:passwd_exec_t:s0 fedora-24/bin/passwd
$ ls -Z /usr/bin/passwd
system_u:object_r:passwd_exec_t:s0 /usr/bin/passwd
```

Attempting to run `restorecon -Rv /` inside the container does nothing.  IIRC libselinux detects when it's run in a container, and will not do anything.

### Solution

We need to run from outside the container:

```
restorecon -Rv fedora-24/
```

It makes sure *all* the SELinux labels are reset.  (To the value expected by the container host, i.e. unlabelled).  Then we can set the root password successfully.

Comment: Testing Fedora 23 (host) looks very similar. In the process, I noticed `etc/passwd-` (the backup copy) _is_ labelled `passwd_file_t`. So I think the mismatch is explained by an rpm script running `useradd`. It must be run with libselinux disabled, same as when running inside the container. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1374427#c2

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with a bootstrapped Cent OS 8 userspace.

Identified problems with

```
[root@- bootstrapped_base_systems]# ls -Z centos8/bin/passwd
system_u:object_r:passwd_exec_t:s0 centos8/bin/passwd
[root@- bootstrapped_base_systems]# ls -Z centos8/etc/passwd
unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 centos8/etc/passwd
```

(`etc/passwd` was good in this case)

Fixed with

```
[root@- bootstrapped_base_systems]# chcon -v unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 centos8/bin/passwd
changing security context of 'centos8/bin/passwd'
```

Verified changed with

```
[root@- bootstrapped_base_systems]# ls -Z centos8/bin/passwd
unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 centos8/bin/passwd
```